# Unable to decode json object using php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to read a json object that is sent from a Rest Api call. However, i get a notice saying  Undefined index. Is there anything i am missing ?

Notice: Undefined index subnet line 7

php

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://xyz:aldkhfuycdhjrrirfjfjkfj@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/IpAddresses.json'); 

$data = json_decode($response,true);

echo "Gateway: ".$data["subnet"][0]["gateway"];
echo "NetMask: ".$data["subnet"][0]["netmask"];

echo "Done";
?>
```

IpAddresses.json

```
[
   {
      "id":12345,
      "subnet":{
         "netmask":"255.255.255.255",
         "gateway":"192.168.255.255"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":56789,
      "subnet":{
         "netmask":"255.255.255.255",
         "gateway":"192.168.255.255"
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close:

```
echo "Gateway: ".$data[0]["subnet"]["gateway"];
echo "NetMask: ".$data[0]["subnet"]["netmask"];
```

Write it like you read it: you want the first item's subnet netmask and gateway.

```
                                 ^      ^          ^ 
                                [0] ['subnet'] ['netmask']
```

Comment: thank you .. is it possible to determine the number of items in $data ? I was planning to run a for loop ? example $data[n]["subnet"]["gateway"] wondering hwo to determine the n ?

Comment: Sure. It's just a normal numerically keyed multidimensional array. `count()` and for loops work just fine. (As do foreach loops).